# Model stop without reason

Tags: anylogic

I get the following error many times in one day, when I want to build my model. Also my model stop without any reason frequently.

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loosing your connection to the database. Likely, this is caused by using a file cloud backup like DropBox or similar which might accidentally destroy some internals without you noticing.

Best have a clean model file setup that you manually backup yourself.

(Or you accidentally deleted some dbase files in your model folder)

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin. I will try to use a clean model file setup.